# How do I retrieve the template URL that is currently loaded in my Angular app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I want to know which template URL is loaded inside a `<div ng-view>`, but I don't want to make changes to the app. Reason is I want to write a bookmarklet that returns the current template URL for any app with routing.

I tried `angular.element('[ng-view]').controller()`, but that only returned an empty object.

Alternatively, I could do something like

1. Retrieve the app by getting it from the element that has the `ng-app` directive
2. Retrieve `$route` dynamically from the app
3. `window.alert($route.current.templateUrl)`

But I couldn't get 1 and 2 to work.

So again my question:
**How do I retrieve the template URL that is currently loaded in my Angular app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, figured it out:

```
// 1
var appInjector = angular.element(document.querySelector('[ng-app]')).injector();
// 2
var route = appInjector.get('$route');
// 3
window.alert($route.current.loadedTemplateUrl);
```